# ListView cut last item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a fragment with this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer">
    <My.Views.NoResultPanel
        style="@style/default_no_result_panel"
        android:id="@+id/noResultPanel"
        local:textID="@string/no_chat" />
    <My.Views.LoadingPanel
        style="@style/default_loading_panel"
        android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
        local:textID="@string/loading_chat" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
    <View
        style="@style/default_divider"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</FrameLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="8dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAttachment"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_attachment_grey600_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgVisibility"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgAttachment"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:hint="@string/write_a_message_here" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgVisibility"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_eye_grey600_24dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgSend" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSend"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_grey600_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I need to emulate a Chat so I'm using android:stackFromBottom

The problem is that when I open that fragment for the first time, I find the last item "cutted".
This is a screenshot of the fragment.

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

**Updated code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAttachment"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_attachment_grey600_24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/Default_clicked_view_rounded" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgVisibility"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgAttachment"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:inputType="textShortMessage"
        android:hint="@string/write_a_message_here" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgVisibility"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_eye_grey600_24dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgSend"
        android:background="@drawable/Default_clicked_view_rounded" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgSend"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_grey600_24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/Default_clicked_view_rounded" />
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer">
    <My.Views.NoResultPanel
        style="@style/default_no_result_panel"
        android:id="@+id/noResultPanel"
        local:textID="@string/no_chat" />
    <My.Views.LoadingPanel
        style="@style/default_loading_panel"
        android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
        local:textID="@string/loading_chat" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
    <View
        style="@style/default_divider"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try removing `android:stackFromBottom="true"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Your FrameLayout is match parent so it is covering the entire screen first so is not sure of the new layout below it @+id/footer...on the top of it you have overlaying bottom RelativeLayout which is footer so just change your layout to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
  //your Footer Layout will always stay in bottom
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="8dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAttachment"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_attachment_grey600_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgVisibility"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgAttachment"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:hint="@string/write_a_message_here" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgVisibility"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_eye_grey600_24dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgSend" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSend"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_grey600_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>


//your FrameLayout now will adjust above footer
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer">     --------change from +id to id now
    <My.Views.NoResultPanel
        style="@style/default_no_result_panel"
        android:id="@+id/noResultPanel"
        local:textID="@string/no_chat" />
    <My.Views.LoadingPanel
        style="@style/default_loading_panel"
        android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
        local:textID="@string/loading_chat" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
    <View
        style="@style/default_divider"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update:**
Please try and add `android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"` attribute to listView

> Sets the transcript mode for the list. In transcript mode, the list scrolls to the bottom to make new items visible when they are added.In this way the list will automatically scroll to the bottom.

Must be one of the following constant values you refer [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:transcriptMode).

[Reference](http://gmariotti.blogspot.in/2013/07/quick-tips-for-listview-build-layout.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. I updated the open post this the updated code

Comment: Have you tried above solution and giving bottom margin to the Framlayout

Comment: Tryed with android:layout_marginBottom="56dp" but the problem remains

Comment: This did the trick :) Thank you! Do you know why that attribute is required?

Comment: @user3471528 I have added the reason and reference for more information so you can try with other values of it as well

Answer (score 1):

Replace your parent RelativeLayout with a LinearLayout with vertical orientation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weight="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer">
        ....
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">
        ....
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The FrameLayout will match the parent height